# Uploading a blob url to azure storage?

Tags: javascript, azure, blob

I have the URL to a blob which I'm trying to upload to azure storage, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of doing this as none of the APIs handle uploading a blob url directly.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('taskcontainer', 'myfile.png', blobUrl, (error, result, response) => {

            });
```

Which doesn't work, I've tried to find ways to read the blob url to a readable stream and upload that but haven't gotten very far either.

I basically have a file selected by the user using [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) which provides me with a blob url (which can look like this: blob:http://localhost:3000/cd8ba70e-5877-4112-8131-91c594be8f1e) pointing to the local file. My goal is to now upload that blob url to an azure container.

Firebase storage has a 'put' function which allows you to upload the blob from a url: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
            var blobUrl = acceptedFiles[0].preview;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", blobUrl);
            xhr.responseType = "text";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
            xhr.onload = function () {
                const Stream = require('stream')
                const readable = new Stream.Readable()

                readable.push(xhr.responseText);
                readable.push(null);

                blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('taskcontainer', 'myblob.png', readable, xhr.responseText.length, (error, result, response)=>{
                    var ok = 0;
                })
            }
            xhr.send();
```

The file (or parts of it?) seem to get uploaded but the end result is the file type is lost and I can't view the png uploaded..

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to create a new blob from a blob URL. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: nono, I have a blob url, I can get the blob from it if I need to but I'm trying to upload that blob to azure storage. Azure storage does not allow me to upload blobs through its api, it allows uploading through a readable stream, local file, text or browser file and I need to find a way to turn the blob url into something I can upload..

Comment: I'm confused :). So you have a blob URL like myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.png and you want to upload a file from your local computer that gets saved as myblob.png. Can you please edit your question and provide more details?

Comment: oh dear ok I updated with a bit more detail, hope that clarifies my intentions :)

Comment: Aah....When you say `blob`, you actually mean blob representing local file and not Azure Blob. Can you share what this blob URL looks like?

Comment: yep, just added it - when viewed in my local browser I can see the image I'm trying to upload..

Comment: Will it be possible for you to create a gist on Github with the complete code that you have? I can take that code and try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService('', '');

blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('nodecontainer', 'AzureDC', 'azure_center.png', function(error, result, response) {
  publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
}, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Check this **[`code snippet`](https://gist.github.com/tomconte/d8bf183398180a291011)** to upload blob to azure storage

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the directory to the local file, all I have is a blob url...

Comment: oh yes I saw that and did try it, but when I have a blob how do I upload that blob to azure? I don't see any function which allows me to upload a blob object..

Comment: did that link help?